# event.target and .get() returns same type but is not?

Tags: jquery

My main goal is to prevent the .click function on a specific child object.
To achieve this, I check if the clicked element is NOT that specific child.

HTML:

```
<p class="participate_session_red">
  <input ...> <label> TEXT </label>
  <span class="participate_session_more">
  </span>
</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".participate_session_red").click(function(e){
    if(e.target != $(this).find(".participate_session_more").get())
    {
        $(this).find(".participate_session_more").slideToggle();
    }
});
```

So to check if my code works I just use alert to get the current object.

```
alert(e.target); returns that element that was clicked. For example:
```

> [object HTMLParagraphElement],[object HTMLLabelElement],[object HTMLSpanElement], ...

```
alert($(this).find(".participate_session_more").get()); returns only
```

> [object HTMLSpanElement]

So theoretically both can return [object HTMLSpanElement] and when this happens my code is still performed even when it shouldn't.

Comment: The result of get() is an array, so it makes no sense to directly compare that with the e.target value. You need to see if the array _contains_ the target item or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) with no argument returns an **array**. An array can never be equal to a DOM element.

If you want to see if `e.target` is not the *first* matching element from your `find`, pass `0` into `get`:

```
if (e.target != $(this).find(".participate_session_more").get(0))
```

Alternately, you can see if the jQuery object returned by the `find` contains `e.target` via [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element):

```
if ($(this).find(".participate_session_more").index(e.target) == -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter test to write is to use `is()` or `hasClass()` which both return booleans

```
$(".participate_session_red").click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('.participate_session_more'))
    {
        $(this).find(".participate_session_more").slideToggle();
    }
});
```